# Best way to use navigation controller for uipopoverview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I want to push to another view from a `popoverview`. For that purpose I had a taken navigation controller to that popover. And also its working fine.

The problem occurs in the second view. To allow the user to send an email i show a mail composer. But i am getting two navigation controllers.

Here is the code for the first popoverview:

```
SettingsVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsVC"];
vc.delegate = self;
UINavigationController *naviCon = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:vc];

self.settingsPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:naviCon];

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(974.f, 36.f, 0, 0);

 self.settingsPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 250);
[self.settingsPopover presentPopoverFromRect:frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Try to present the mail composer modally inside a popover

Comment: how to present mail composer inside popover? @beryllium

Comment: `[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:{}];`

Comment: used the same code but i am getting mailcomposer on main view not in popoverview

Comment: because you need to call it not in main view - you have to do it **inside a popover content**. I guess it is a SettingsVC. In my example `self` mean a place where a new modal controller will be showed.

Comment: i am calling in popover view controller only @beryllium

Answer (score 0):

When I needed something similar, I called the MFMailComposeViewController from the ViewController which calls the PopoverController (the parent ViewController) and also included the delegate ect in that ViewController.
I defined a protocol in the ContentViewController of the PopoverViewController which informs the parent ViewController when it needs to call the MFMailComposeViewController.
All worked perfectly without a problem... hope that helps

Comment: I am getting same problem in others views when i am calling MFMailComposeViewController . If i did not use navigation in popover its working fine otherwise i am getting two navigation controllers